# How to identify the request comes from a web proxy in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to make a statistical record to identify how many visitors come using web proxies to my asp.net mvc site.

How to identify them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this useful.  If not, this is a good read, applicable to both webforms and mvc.

http://haacked.com/archive/2006/10/11/A_Gotcha_Identifying_the_Users_IP_Address.aspx